# "The Database Could Not Lock Table" Error when trying to close report, kill current tables tied to report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a report that updates from tables that export from a separate database.  I have the report on a timer to requery every 5 minutes.  The process that I am trying to execute is close the report, kill the tables behind the query that generates the report, import the the updated files to tables with the same names that were just killed and reexecute the query and report.  I keep getting Run-time error '3211': "The Database Could Not Lock Table".

Code is below and any help for this novice is greatly appreciated.

```vb
Private Sub Report_Timer()

'Close Report
DoCmd.Close acReport, "SMT Progress Report"

'Kill existing tables
Set dbs = CurrentDb
dbs.TableDefs.Delete ("SMT2Updated") ' error here
dbs.TableDefs.Delete ("SMT3Updated")
dbs.TableDefs.Delete ("SMT4Updated")
dbs.TableDefs.Delete ("SMT5Updated")
Set dbs = Nothing

'Import Files to Tables
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "SMT2Updated", "\\ct13nt003\mfg\SMT_Schedule_Files\SMT Line Progress Files\SMT2Updated.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "SMT3Updated", "\\ct13nt003\mfg\SMT_Schedule_Files\SMT Line Progress Files\SMT3Updated.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "SMT4Updated", "\\ct13nt003\mfg\SMT_Schedule_Files\SMT Line Progress Files\SMT4Updated.xlsx", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "SMT5Updated", "\\ct13nt003\mfg\SMT_Schedule_Files\SMT Line Progress Files\SMT5Updated.xlsx", True

'Refresh and Open Query/Report
Me.Requery
DoCmd.OpenReport "SMT Progress Report", acViewReport

'Export status file
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "SMT Progress Report Export Only", acFormatPDF, "\\ct13nt003\MFG\SMT Live Report\SMTLive" & "_" & Format(Now(), "mmddyyyy-hhmm") & ".pdf", False

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that is where I am running into the run-time error.  I assume it is because I am still tied to the table when the script is being evaluated.

Comment: @HansUp That is part of it, but I also want to display the report on a large monitor showing our job status.  So I need to keep the report open.  That's why I initially open the report with a button from the form, then use the timer function to continually refresh the report with the most up-to-date information being captured in the other database.  So I need the report to open initially, then close, then kill the existing tables, then import the updated tables, then open the updated report.  Then repeat the cycle every 5 mins.

Comment: Instead of dropping and then re-importing the tables, I think you could execute a `DELETE` query followed by an "append query" for each of those 4 tables.  Although Access doesn't allow you to drop the table while the report is using it, you can discard all the rows it contains and insert fresh rows.

Comment: @HansUp - So obvious, yet genius.  That... is the right answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I made a form filtering a query and tried to make a report. I got this same error saying can not lock table by database engine.

What I did is simply gone to the report in desighn view and changed Record Locks as No Locks. It worked.